# audiocontext doesn't play wav files

Tags: javascript, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I am trying to learn how to use Audiocontext to give surrounding effects to my sounds.

I've spent so many hours trying to set up a simple example on jfiddle or similar and I was frustrated to the extreme, unabel to set up the simplest of examples, untill I found the following link:

https://codepen.io/Rumyra/pen/qyMzqN/

Which includes this audio reference:

```
    <audio src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/858/outfoxing.mp3" crossorigin="anonymous" ></audio>
```

It works!, but then I replaced the .mp3 file on the  HTML section for one of my own files which is a wav file and it stopped working. I tried another wav file: https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/StarWars3.wav and it didn't work either.

It seems that my problem all this time was that I was using a wav file for audiocontext when it is not permited?, didn't find any clue about it on all the tutorials I found, can anyone confirm that the problem is the format of the files I wanted to use?

Comment: It's about your websites cors policy, www2.cs.uic.edu doesn't allow other domains to get files.

Comment: But when I try to run a jsfiddle with this: `<audio controls>
  <source src="https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/StarWars3.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>` it works perfectly